# incremental/selective sync remote system

Tags: java, database

i am developing a solution where i persist by a webapp different kind of entities such as users, groups, departments info on a central database and ldap for authentication. But the final user will interact with the data from a remote location (his office, the nodes), connected with a very unstable WAN connection between the central server and the remote office. So we would like to replicate a subset of the information we had on the central server locally at every remote node, in this way the user will not experience connection problems, during the everyday usage.
Actually i am searching for a solution/product/framework which gives me the possibility to:

1. Replicate selectively and incrementally the data and map it to multiple nodes
2. Replicating the data asynchronously, and support network disconnections and guaranteed of delivery.
3. Having a web UI to monitor the process, and the status of remote node, if they are in sync or not.

My first idea is developing it on top of a integration middle ware as Apache Camel, using JMS for transport, and deploying the server part on the central node, and client side at the local office server. 
But i am wondering, since i think it's a very common need, are out there no ready to use solution/product available to reach the same result with less custom coding?

Database: PostgreSQL

Comment: Do the remote users update the information in the database or they only read it ?

Comment: You might be interested in JSON Patch.

Comment: the remote nodes will only read the database. The changes are done only at central level and should be propagated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the configuration described in the following [Comparison of Different Solutions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/different-replication-solutions.html)

Among all the options described in this article, you can probably investigate the options: "Trigger-Based Master-Standby Replication" and "Asynchronous Multimaster Replication".

The first one is ok if the remote users can only read, otherwise you need to have more than one master. It has to be asynchronous given that the network is not stable.

For the second option you can use [bucardo](https://bucardo.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Comment: yes i considered bucardo too, but it is too low level, since i have an ldap and database to keep in sync, i thought it would be  a better solution to transfer the models from one server to the other.

Comment: @Joel Do you need to modify the ldap on the remote machine? I mean, the user will update the ldap running on the local node?

Comment: no, the ldap is updated only by the central webapp, so the remote user will just authenticate against it.

Comment: I am probably missing something. If the remote nodes are all "read only", why don't you use bucardo for the database and a standard synchronization for the ldap? I do not think that bucardo is "low level".

Comment: because if you use two different ways to update them, you can be out of sync with one of them easily. The update on LDAP and DB should be in the same transaction, if you want to preserve the consistency between the two